# Azure data factory - pass multiple items to foreach to use as parameters?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a table that looks like the below stored in SQL.. it contains a LOT of rows which I need to loop through.

```
ContactID       Fromdate           Todate
1               01-Jan-2022      01-Feb-2022
2               01-Jan-2022      01-Feb-2022
```

I have a lookup activity to read from this table, and I need to pass the output of this lookup activity to my foreach so I can amend the linked service to use a dynamic API link..

[image]

As of now I am able to pass the ContactID into the foreach and everything works fine.. however I now need to pass in the fromdate and todate also but I am not sure how to do this.. can someone explain the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Use `@item().contactID` ,`@item().Fromdate`, `@item().Todate` respectively in dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to understand that will inform your answer.

First: you do not "pass parameters" to a ForEach. Instead, ForEach accesses variables and parameters just like any other activity. All variables and parameters are global in the context of the pipeline run.

Second: in the case of a ForEach, you do specify the item list to iterate over. By specifying the output value of the Lookup, it should be one row per iteration. Inside a ForEach, you can reference the current iteration by using `@item()`, so you should be able to reference properties like `@item().Fromdate`.

Third: because of the global nature of variables, you may seriously want to consider checking "Sequential". Running iterations in parallel that reference variables can lead to unexpected results.

Fourth: you say there are "a LOT of rows". I believe Lookup has a hard limit of 5,000 rows, so you should be aware of that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for bringing the 5k limit to my attention.. I didn't know this..

I managed to fix my solution following the instruction on this video..  :) recommend it for anyone needing to do the same as I did

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4yFXGbhYZI